# Tkinter: How do I make a button assign a variable a number

Tags: python, variables, button, tkinter

I want to ask the question "Would you like 1,2 or 3 tickets?"
I would like to make it so that there would be 3 buttons, once pressed a variable  would be assigned 1,2 or 3.

I have tried using message box although that only gives a yes or no answer.
How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `command` function and it will call a function whenever the button is clicked.

```
import tkinter

tickets = 0

def ticket():
    tickets = 1
    print(tickets)

def twotickets():
    tickets = 2
    print(tickets)

def threetickets():
    tickets = 3
    print(tickets)

window = tkinter.Tk()

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="How many tickets would you like?")
button = tkinter.Button(window, text="One ticket", command=ticket)
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Two tickets", command=twotickets)
button3 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Three tickets", command=threetickets)

label.pack()
button.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

You can have as many of these buttons as you'd like as long as you bind them to a function if you want them to do anything. Also, remember if you'd like to use this changed variable, declare it global where you'd like to use it.